# Finding Fourier coefficients of $x\mapsto e^{2\cos x}\cos(2 \sin x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Consider the function $$g:[0,2\pi]\to \mathbb{R}, \quad x\mapsto2e^{2\cos x}\cos(2 \sin x) -1$$

I would like to find its **Fourier coefficients**.

Since $g$ is an even function, the Fourier coefficients are given as $$\alpha_k = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} g(x) \cos(kx) dx \quad (k\in\mathbb{N}).$$

I'm not sure if this is helpful but I've written $g$ as follows: $g(x) = e^{2e^{ix}} + e^{2e^{-ix}}-1$.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** You may observe that, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
e^{2\cos x}\cos(2 \sin x)&=\Re \left(e^{2\cos x}e^{2i\sin x}\right)\\\\
&=\Re \left(e^{2e^{ix}}\right)\\\\
&=\Re \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(2e^{ix}\right)^n}{n!}\right)\\\\
&=\Re \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^ne^{inx}}{n!}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^n\cos (nx)}{n!}\\\\
\end{align}
$$ then by **the uniqueness** of the Fourier coefficients you obtain
$$
b_n =  \frac{2^{n+1}}{n!}\pi, \quad n=1,2,3,\ldots .
$$ with
$$
b_n = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{2\cos x}\cos(2 \sin x) \cos(nx) dx.
$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate why uniqueness implies that $b_n =  \frac{2^{n+1}}{n!}\pi$? Shouldnt the integral at the bottom be from $0$ to $\pi$?

Comment: @iwriteonbananas If a function admits $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum b_n \cos nx$ and $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum b'_n \cos nx$ then $b_n=b'_n$. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. you wrote $e^{2\cos x}\cos(2 \sin x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^n\cos (nx)}{n!}$, so shouldnt we have $b_n = \frac{2^{n+1}}{n!}$? Where does the $\pi$ come from?

Comment: @iwriteonbananas Just because we define $\displaystyle \beta_n$ as $\displaystyle \beta_n:=\frac{1}{\pi}\!\int ...$